# Getting java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.String to java.util.UUID in my spring boot application

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

we are recently upgraded the Spring boot version to 3.2.2 in my project. After upgrade we are getting below error while calling repository method.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.String to java.util.UUID
```

I'm using Postresql as my DB

Hibernate-core:6.4.1 its getting used,
Java 21 we are using

I'm attaching the code snippet for you reference.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bulk_user")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
@Getter
@Setter
public class BulkEntity {

    @Id
    @JdbcTypeCode(Types.VARCHAR)
    @Column(name = "row_id", nullable = false)
    private UUID rowId;

    @JdbcTypeCode(Types.VARCHAR)
    @Column(name = "bulk_upload_id", length = 50, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private UUID bulkId;

    @Column(name = "data", length = 500, nullable = false)
    private String data;

    @Column(name = "application", length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String application;
}
```

here, **bulk_upload_id** is declared as **varchar(500)** in Database

Below is my Repository

```
@Repository
public interface BulkUserRepository extends JpaRepository<BulkEntity, UUID> {
  @Query("select b from BulkEntity b where b.bulkId =:bulkId")
  List<BulkEntity> getAllUsersWithBulkId(@Param("bulkId")UUID bulkId);
}
```

Below is the code snippet which we are using to call Repository method

```
List<BulkEntity> bulkEntityList = bulkUserRepository.getAllUsersWithBulkId(bulkId);
```

here bulkId datatype is **UUID** and **bulkUserRepository** object is injected in Constructor. Please suggest some solution for this.

Its working fine in another Entity in the same project

repo method call

```
userRepository.findByKcUserId(userModel.getKcUserId());
```

**userModel.getKcUserId()** will return UUID value

Repo method

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.kcUserId=?1")
Optional<User> findByKcUserId(UUID kcUserId);
```

Entity field

```
@JdbcTypeCode(Types.VARCHAR)
@Column(name = "kc_user_Id", length = 50, unique = true, nullable = false)
private UUID kcUserId;
```

**kcUserId** is declared it as **varchar(36) in DB**. here its working fine

Comment: a String is not an instance of type UUID. How does this surprise you?

Comment: @Stultuske Actually the same case properly working in another entity in the same project. that is surprising me.

Comment: @Stultuske added the working code also

Comment: UUID uuid = java.util.UUID.fromString(String name)

Comment: @SamuelMarchant Why do I need to convert this as UUID, its already UUID only

Comment: At first, everything seems ok.
@KaviChinna can you provide the code above this line: `List<BulkEntity> bulkEntityList = bulkUserRepository.getAllUsersWithBulkId(bulkId);`?

I would like to see where bulkId comes from.

Comment: @rafavilomar Thanks for your time. Its fixed now. The issue was I have one more UUID field in BulkEntity for that I haven't added that  @JdbcTypeCode(Types.VARCHAR) annotation. That was causing the issue. It was my mistake. Sorry for that. Thanks all